# Jmeter - how can I run a request x amount of times, then next request once? also repeat this entire test case x amount times

Tags: jmeter

[image]
I have a task that I want to use Jmeter to accomplish.
bascailly, the request is an API call.
I want to call this request 10,000 times, once the 10,000 requests are done, only then do the next request, but only once.
afterward I want to repeat this two step test x amount of times

how can I achieve this in Jmeter?
thank you!

edit:
my apology for the messy post, still learning how to use comment format...

Answer (score 0):

- > I want to call this request 10,000 times

  put it under the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) and set the "Loop Count" to `10000`
- > only then do the next request, but only once

  just add the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler
- > want to repeat this two step test x amount of times

  you can control how many times the whole sequence is executed on [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level, it also has "Loop Count" input

Also if the request is an API call you might also need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) and configure it to send the relevant [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header

Comment: Thank You so much!
I will check this out, just a follow up question -
for the second part (do it once) should I create a new thread(user) for it, or can I keep it under the same thread(user)?

I will post an image of my current setup